# Intro to Event Queues for Web App

Tags: perl, events

I'm trying to implement a basic but flexible "event queue" so that my web app can go run subs asynchronously.  The way I have working for me now is the app writes a record to an "event queue" table in my database with info on what to do and when to fire.  Then I have a daemon script that queries that table periodically and if something needs to be done, it fires it off.

I'd like to start moving towards watchers using something like AnyEvent or EV so I'm not hitting my database so often, but try as I might, I can't find good info on "best practices" for setting something like this up.  AnyEvent's documentation is pretty good, but it seems to assume you know how your events should be passed around...which I don't.

What should my watcher be watching?  A file?  If so, what should be in that file?  I don't need to send a whole bunch of data around, I just basically need something that says, "go off and run this sub right now"

I would greatly appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

**EDIT:**
It's been requested that I be more specific:  The events I'm trying to fire are various.  Sometimes it's an email that needs sending, sometimes it's some DB work, sometimes I just need an action to be delayed for a few hours or days.  In all cases, I have some sort of backend script to handle the action, I just need a way for my frontend (web app) to tell my backend, "hey I need you to go do this in x minutes" or "I need you to do this now"

Comment: front-end can discuss backend with REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) which is built to be non-blocking and respond asynchronously. It even uses EV internally if you have it installed. To get started read the doc for `Mojolicious::Lite` and then the Guides (in order) from here: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc

So what is it that you are actually trying to do? Until you describe what it is you actually need, I can't help you any further that that.

Comment: How do I know that `EV` is used by Mojolicious? Is installed libevent enough, or some additional perl module is also required?

Comment: within the program it will set the env var MOJO_REACTOR or else you can see what class is seen in `Mojo::IOLoop->reactor`

Answer (score 0):

There are some CPAN modules in order to run asynchronous tasks via message queues. Examples:

- [Queue::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Queue%3a%3aDBI)
- [POE::Component::MessageQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE%3a%3aComponent%3a%3aMessageQueue)
- [Any::MQ](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyMQ)